# Navigate from a side bar without page reload in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have three Index pages that contain 3 partial views each. Clicking on an anchor tag on the side bar loads the Index page containing the partial views.

I have an issue with the side bar getting refreshed when navigating to a page. How can I load an index page with partial views without refreshing the side bar as well? I only want the page itself to render and refresh not the sidebar.

I am rendering the side bar partial in the main Layout like this   <partialname="_SideBar.cshtml" />

_Sidebar.cshtml i.e navigation menu:

```
   <div class="collapse" id="showDashboards">
            <ul class="no-bullets sidebar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" id="azure-nav" href="@Url.Action("AzureContent", "Azure")">
                        <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="30" height="30"><use xlink:href="#azure" /></svg>
                        Azure
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link text-white azure-reports">
                        <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="30" height="30"><use xlink:href="#reports" /></svg>
                        Reports
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" id="o365-nav" href="@Url.Action("Index", "O365")">
                        <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="30" height="30"><use xlink:href="#o365" /></svg>
                        Office 365
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link text-white o365-reports" href="@Url.Action("Index", "O365Reports")"> 
                        <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="30" height="30"><use xlink:href="#reports" /></svg>
                        Reports
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want to use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).

*Since I'm not sure what your other views (besides `_Sidebar.cshtml`) look like, the examples I provide are simplified, and you'll have to adapt them to fit your project. I'm also assuming you're using jQuery, but if not, you'll have to make some changes there as well.*

Since your sidebar is currently in your main Layout page, you'll want to create one main Index page that holds an area for the other 3 partial views to be loaded into, and a section for javascript. At its most basic, it'll be something like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";    // path to your main Layout
}

<div id="nav-ajax-target"></div>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        // javascript in next code snippet
    </script>
}
```

Then, you'll add a click event to your `<a>` tags in the navbar. This example utilizes the existing `href` attribute you're already using.

```
// add this in the script section above

$("#showDashboards a.nav-link").click(function (e) {
    // prevent the default action of click an <a> tag
    // (navigating away from the current page)
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // get the value of the "href" attribute of the clicked link
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    
    if (href) {
        // make an ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            method: "GET",
            // load the result into the "nav-ajax-target" div
            done: function(data) {
                $("#nav-ajax-target").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```